# GravityForms, GravityViews, action hook to know when record is approved

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I have GravityForms and GravityViews in my WP instance. I am building a system where a user can book a reservation using GravityForms. If that reservation is for 3 or more nights, then that agent is awarded 3 points. An admin agent can then view all reservations in GravityViews from multiple agents. The admin agent's job is to review all the booked reservations and click a button in the table to "approve" the agent to award him the points.

I am not sure what the best approach is to allow the admin agent to "approve" each record he is viewing in GravityViews. I feel like I need to add a column to the view that has a checkbox (approve/disapprove) and wire up "add_action()" to this check/uncheck event. When the admin agent approves an agent's record, I want to do some other actions, such as update the user's total points earned and remove the record from the current GravityView.

Does GravityViews provide this functionality? If not, should I create a custom table view in WP where I have one column that is my action (check/uncheck) and listen for event clicks?

WP has so many plugins that I am not sure if I should use something that exists or develop this custom functionality from scratch. I am new with WP, so I am limited on knowing what exists.

If I were to do this outside of WP, I would load up my page, display a table view of the GravityForm data, append a column to each record that has a checkbox in it, and when the user clicks that checkbox, I would update the database and refresh my current view. Being unfamiliar with WP, I am not sure what all I can do because all I have access to is functions.php and functions.js.

Thanks for the help.